# Porque el connectionstring me esta borrando el password a la hora de crear la conexión a la base de datos sql server?

Tags: c#

Estoy conectandome a una base de datos con SQLDataClient en C#. Estoy usando el siguiente método:

```
 public static string stringConection = "";

    public async Task<List<object>> SelectFromDatabase(Conexion con,string consulta)
    {


        List<object> resultados = new List<object>();

        try
        {
            bool hayConsulta = consulta != null ? true : false;

            if (hayConsulta)
            {
                bool servidor = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Servidor) ? true : false;

                bool bd = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.BD) ? true : false;

                bool usuario = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Usuario) ? true : false;

                bool clave = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Password) ? true : false;



                if (servidor && bd && usuario && clave )
                {
                    stringConection= "Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";";

                    using (var conexion=new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        conexion.ConnectionString = stringConection;

                       await conexion.OpenAsync();

                        using (var comando=new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
                        {
                            await comando.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                            using (var reader=await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                            {
                                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                                {


                                    foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < item.FieldCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            if (item.GetValue(i) != null)
                                            {

                                                var anonimo = new { columna = item.GetName(i), valor = item.GetValue(i) };


                                                resultados.Add(anonimo);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    return resultados;

                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return null;
        }


    }
```

Sin embargo sucede algo muy extraño. Cuando le paso el stringConection al ConnectionString de la instancia de el SQLDataConnection me elimina el Password de el connectionString y el SQLCommand no me trae ningun registro.

Como pueden ver aquí tiene todo el string correcto :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ya después del OpenAsync() y antes de ejecutar el query me cambia el string:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me corto el Password !!!!. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que desaparezca el password es por diseño, básicamente una medida de seguridad. En la documentación de [SqlConnection.ConnectionString](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString) se especifica:

> La ConnectionString es similar a una cadena de conexión de OLE DB, pero no es idéntica. A diferencia de OLE DB o ADO, la cadena de conexión que se devuelve es la misma que la ConnectionStringdel conjunto de usuarios, menos la información de seguridad si el valor de Persist Security info se establece en false (valor predeterminado). El proveedor de datos de .NET Framework para SQL Server no conserva o devuelve la contraseña en una cadena de conexión a menos que establezca Persist Security info en true.

Comment: Es cierto eso es verdad le puse true y si me muestra el password. Alguna idea de porque no trae los datos ?

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez eso sería otra cuestión :) Te recomendaría que crearas una nueva pregunta especificando que la consulta no te devuelve resultados y dejaras esta dado que puede ser interesante para otros que tuvieran la misma curiosidad que tu.